# xamarin error when trying set SetVideoFrameRate

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mediarecorder

i am working on xamarin. I am using MediaRecorder, i just want to set the frame rate but when i set it  `recorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);` i get error of

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException:

I am not sure if it device cant handle it or is there certain way of getting it to work. I am just using simple MediaRecorder.

```
MediaRecorder recorder;

video.StopPlayback();

recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//--
recorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
// recorder.SetCaptureRate(150);
recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(video.Holder.Surface);
recorder.Prepare();
recorder.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `SetVideoFramerate` before `SetOutputFormat`. Move that method call under `SetOutputFormat` and it will work.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
recorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30); // Move it here
```

Android actually has a great documentation that tells you what exceptions each method can throw. This is a quote from the [MediaRecorder's page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoFrameRate(int)):

> **Throws**
>
> IllegalStateException if it is called after prepare() or before setOutputFormat(). NOTE: On some devices that have auto-frame rate, this sets the maximum frame rate, not a constant frame rate. Actual frame rate will vary according to lighting conditions.

Comment: would you know any thing about setting the exposure on camera or the focal length of the lens

Comment: @oisin1min [Camera.Parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) is what you're looking for but it's now deprecated. The documentation mentions that you should now use [android.hardware.camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) but I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: thank you. your amazing. would you know any where i could get example for this for android